# MacOS vm_read API seems flaky (no such process)

Tags: macos, memory, kernel, mach

I have some C code calling the Mach vm_read API to grab one or more words from the memory of a different process. I'm able to get it working sometimes (compiling with code signing and running under `sudo`), but other times, I get a kernel error "no such process" even though the process remains unchanged. Is this flakiness a known issue?

Code snippet below. This does not work (`vm_read` returns 1), but it looks identical to code which has in the past:

```
size_t PTR_SIZE = sizeof(void*);
size_t size = PTR_SIZE;

char* rbuffer = malloc(size);

vm_offset_t buffer_pointer;
mach_msg_type_number_t data_cnt;

kernret = vm_read(task, (vm_address_t)start_addr, size, &buffer_pointer, &data_cnt);
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the `task` port, and is that definitely valid?

Comment: @pmdj Using `task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &task)` and receiving KERN_SUCCESS

Comment: I just checked and a Mach return value 1 is `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`, so I'm not sure where you're getting "no such process" from? I guess your `start_addr` value might not be correct? Also, note that `rbuffer` in your code is not used, so I hope you're not expecting any data to turn up in that memory. (for reading to an existing memory buffer, use `vm_read_overwrite()`)

Comment: @pmdj Thanks so much. I called `perror("vmread")` which gave me "No such process". I'll check `start_addr`. Yes, I have a memcpy call later, but perhaps I'll use `vm_read_overwrite()`.

Comment: `perror()` works with `errno` which is entirely separate from the Mach return codes. The latter are defined in `<mach/kern_return.h>`. I don't know if there's an existing function for looking up numeric values and printing the human-readable constant name for these.

Comment: With regard to addresses - don't forget about ASLR: if you're trying to access a statically-allocated variable in the target process where you know the offset in the binary, you'll need to take into account the dynamic base address which varies from run to run.

Comment: @pmdj `mach_error_string` works on kernret to print human-readable strings. I just figured they'd coincide somehow.